# JavaFX - Exclude Text Node from preferred width sizing?

Tags: java, text, dynamic, javafx, width

In converting from Swing to FX we have a number of screens that have a bunch of fields along with a long text description letting the user know what the routine does.

We do not know the width of the screen before it is laid out, so this makes it difficult to call setWrappingWidth on a Text Node.  Without calling setWrappingWidth, then it seems to be the Text Node that determines the size of the Scene (assuming it is very long description and wouldn't wrap without setWrappingWidth being called).

Currently we have a Scene inside a JFXPanel inside a JInternalFrame.  We typically call the pack() method once setScene is called on JFXPanel to have the screen size itself.

I was hoping I could exclude the Text node from the Scene's width calculations and then set the wrapping width once the Scene is sized.  Any suggestions for how to handle this?  Thanks